# "This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment." error with Firebase Google Authentication

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, trusted-types

I am using Firebase authentication to try and have users sign in via Google. I am able to get the authentication to work using the signInWithPopup method however, I would like to use the signInWithRedirect for mobile. I keep getting the error "This document requires 'TrustedScript' assignment." which then prompts me back to the login page after I tried to submit the authentication. I tried using DOMPurify to sanitize the code and create TrustedTypes but to no avail. Any suggestions?

Code for the sign in method:

```
    const signInWithGoogle = async () => {
        if (/Mobi/.test(navigator.userAgent)) {
            const result = await signInWithRedirect(auth, provider);
            await getRedirectResult(auth);
                //do some redirect to other page
                return;
        }
        const result = await signInWithPopup(auth, provider);
        if (result){
            localStorage.setItem('isAuth', true);
            setAuth(true);
            //here would probably need to handle logic if they already did the rating
            navigate('/dailyrating');
        }
    };
```

Comment: hi, is your signInWithPopup opening a new tab instead of creating a popup?